# How to add a class to TD's without text in them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a class to the TD's that doesn't contain any text so that I can remove them all using Jquery. Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title></title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="myjavascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">

</head>

<body>



<table class="counter">


<tr>
<th colspan="2">Goalkeepers</th><th colspan="2">Defenders</th>
<th colspan="2">Midfielders</th><th colspan="2">Forwards</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>1 Wojciech Szczesny<td>0</td></td>
<td>3 Bacary Sagna<td>0</td></td>
<td>7 Tomas Rosicky<td>0</td></td>
<td>9 Lukas Podolski<td>0</td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>13 Emiliano Viviano<td>0</td></td>
<td>6 Laurent Koscielny<td>0</td></td>
<td>8 Mikel Arteta<td>0</td></td>
<td>12 Olivier Giroud<td>0</td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>21 Lukasz Fabianski<td>0</td></td>
<td>4 Per Mertesacker<td>0</td></td>
<td>10 Jack Wilshere<td>0</td></td>
<td>14 Theo Walcott<td>0</td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td>5 Thomas Vermaelen<td>0</td></td>
<td>16 Aaron Ramsey<td>0</td></td>
<td>15 Alex Oxlade-Chamberlain<td>0</td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td>28 Kieran Gibbs<td>0</td></td>
<td>11 Mesut Ozil<td>0</td></td>
<td>22 Yaya Sanogo<td>0</td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td>17 Nacho Monreal<td>0</td></td>
<td>20 Mathieu Flamini<td>0</td></td>
<td>23 Nicklas Bendtner<td>0</td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td>25 Carl Jenkinson<td>0</td></td>
<td>24 Abou Diaby<td>0</td></td>
<td>31 Ryo Miyaichi<td>0</td></td>
</tr>

<tr>

<td><td>0</td></td>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td>58 Gedion Zelalem<td>0</td></td>
<td>44 Serge Gnabry<td>0</td></td>
</tr>



<tr>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td>29 Kim Kallstrom<td>0</td></td>
<td><td>0</td></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td><td>0</td></td>
<td>19 Santi Cazorla<td>0</td></td>
<td><td>0</td></td>
</tr>

</table>







</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Jquery that would remove them:

```
 $("tr td:contains('')").each(function(){
  $(this).siblings('td.hideClass').css('visibility' , 'hidden');

 });
```

I tried using:
    $(tr td:contains(' ')").addClass("hideClass");

But that didn't work. Any help appreciated!

Comment: CSSdoes it too : td:empty {visibility:hidden;} test: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lsdCe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `:empty` selector:

```
$("td:empty").addClass('hideClass')
```

> ### [`:empty` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)
>
> Description: Select all elements that have no children (**including text nodes**).

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YFgur/)

Comment: +1 In OPs code it should work as there is not blank space.... if the td is like `<td> </td>` it won't work - for `:empty` to work it should be `<td></td>`

Comment: @ArunPJohny You're right. But I consider that `<td> </td>` is not an empty element. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to try

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("tr td").filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) == ''
    }).addClass('hideClass')
})
```

Note: In your sample the first set of `td`s are not properly closed - `<td><td>0</td></td>` should be `<td></td><td>0</td>`

Comment: They are closed the way they are supposed to :)

Answer (score 4):

use:

```
$("tr td").each(function(){
  if($(this).html()===""){
   //add class using $(this).addClass('classname');
 }
});
```

Comment: I think you should use `===` instead of `==`. or not?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to actually be looking to hide all TDs that contain '0' rather than all empty TDs.
If you're looking to hide all empty elements, @Ionică Bizău 's answer is fine (using `empty();`).
If you're looking for specific characters, you can still use contains, but you have to be very specific about descendants.

Here's a Fiddle-diddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sickdesigner/5pMcJ/